# How to create a function with return value in knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js

this is my itemModel:

```
var itemModel = function (id,description,picture,totalInventory,retailPrice,dealerPrice,category,brand,unitOfMeasure,createdBy,status,highestCost, lowestCost) {
var self = this;

self.ID = ko.observable(id);
self.Description = ko.observable(description);
self.Picture = ko.observable(picture);
self.TotalInventory = ko.observable(totalInventory);
self.RetailPrice = ko.observable(retailPrice);
self.DealerPrice = ko.observable(dealerPrice);
self.Category = ko.observable(category);
self.Brand = ko.observable(brand);
self.UnitOfMeasure = ko.observable(unitOfMeasure);
self.CreatedBy = ko.observable(createdBy);
self.Status = ko.observable(status);
self.HighestCost = ko.observable(highestCost);
self.LowestCost = ko.observable(lowestCost);};
```

I have this method to get the items

```
self.GetItems = function(){
   $.getJSON("/Items/GetItems",{status: self.ItemStatus()}, function (result) {
      for (var i = 0, j = result.data.length; i < j; i++){
            item = result.data[i];
            underlyingArray.push(new itemModel(
                item.ID,
                item.Description,
                item.Picture,
                ....computetotalinventoryhere...,
                item.RetailPrice,
                item.DelearPrice,
                item.Category,
                item.Brand,
                item.UnitOfMeasure,
                item.CreatedBy,
                item.Status,
                item.HighestCost,
                item.LowestCost
            ));
        }
        self.list.valueHasMutated();
   }
```

};

I want to create a function to compute the total inventory. Is that possible in knockout? or any suggestion on how to do this. thanks.

Comment: Where does underlyingArray variable come from?  Are your missing an assignment  before the for loop ?  Is the total across ALL items in "self.list" or does each itemModel have its own total value

Comment: above that i set the variables 
var item, underlyingArray = self.list();

Comment: What about the other questions... it could influence the answer

Comment: I edited the script above. I added the itemModel.

Answer (score 2):

Use a computed observable

```
var totalInv = ko.computed(function(){
   var total = 0;
   for(var i = 0; i < underlyingArray().length; i++){
       total += underlyingArray()[i].RetailPrice; // OR OTHER VALUES AS NEEDED
   }

   return total;  // or other values as needed
});
```

Comment: If you have to luxury of ES5 I suggest the use of map/reduce instead of for loop with external total variable  "return underlyingArray().map(~selectorFn~).reduce( function(prev, curr) { return prev + curr; }, 0)